# Python Selenium webdriver : Debugging

Tags: python, debugging, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing test in python using selenium webdriver and it's a real pain to debug it.
Let's say my test is like this:

1. Connect
2. Click on "My Account"
3. Click on "Unsubscribe"
4. Disconnect

---

Then:

- When I run the .py file it starts a new browser so if I want to debug the thrid action I have to run all my test. I can't say on my account page and try it a few times.
- The other issue is that the Browser close itself at the end of the test so I can't even understand exactly why it crashed. I only know where it crashed in the code.I tried "driver.quit()" but it's not doing anything.

Is there anyways to make the debugging easy?

Comment: Are you not using an IDE like Eclipse with PyDev plugin for development? If not I suggest you do, the inbuilt debugging system will allow you to step through your code line by line so you can reliably debug your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing user tests, you may want to consider going one step higher and embrace BDD as your testing suite. There is  fabulous library for it in python: [lettuce](http://lettuce.it/index.html), There is a [Selenium webdriver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lettuce_webdriver) for it.

This should make it much easier for you, as it will provide you not only with a very nice way to store, read and manage tests but also a common-ground between them (called terrain) where you can spawn browsers at various states, or even just pass along one from scenario to scenario if that is required.

Heck with use of [hooks](http://lettuce.it/reference/terrain.html#lettuce-hooks) you can restart the state of a browser between states, which seems to be exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: The tools you linked look cool thank you very much. The only thing I'm missing now is the tools to analyse easily the webpage I usualy do that with selenium IDE, should I keep doing that or is there something better?

Comment: @Bajo hmm i usually just go with developer tools that come with chrome, seems to be enough for me. Keep in mind that whatever you used for selenium before, you can still use with this tool (it's only a driver).